# Imaginary part in asymptotics of hypergeometric function

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, power-series, divergent-series, hypergeometric-function

I am working with the function

$$ _2F_3\left(n+\frac{1}{2},n+\frac{3}{2};n,n+\frac{5}{2},2 n+1;x^2\right).$$

Evaluating the numerical value of this or plotting it indicates that this is always real for integer $n$. However, when I use Mathematica to find the expansion of this function near $x=\infty$ using `Series[HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 + n, 3/2 + n}, {n, 5/2 + n, 1 + 2 n}, x^2], {x, \[Infinity], 2}]`, the expansion has imaginary parts.

Why does this happen? How can I find the asymptotic behavior of this function? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You allow integer $n \le 0$?  That may not make sense.  For $n>0$, of course it is real... the series has infinite radius of convergence and positive coefficients.

Comment: You can get the full asymptotics via [$(16.11.8)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.11.E8). Note that the second and third terms are complex conjugates of each other for positive real $z$ and hence their sum is real.

Comment: @Gary. Thanks for the link. Any idea about the $a_n$ I wrote ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It is $2^{2n - 1} (2n + 3)n!(n - 1)!$

Comment: @Gary. many thanks ! Meanwhile I found https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263796676_A_note_on_the_asymptotic_expansion_of_generalized_hypergeometric_functions

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The one that is relevant for the OP is https://www.researchgate.net/publication/361005945_Asymptotic_Expansion_of_the_Generalized_Hypergeometric_Function_pFqz_as_z_for_p_q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that, for general $n$, you could obtain this expansion even if you add `Assumptions -> n > 0 && n Integer`

For $n=3$ for example, your command gives
$$\left(\frac{1728 i}{\pi 
   x^7}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^8\right)\right) \exp
   \left(-2 x-\frac{7 i \pi
   }{2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^3\right)\right)+\left(
   \frac{1728 i}{\pi 
   x^7}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^8\right)\right) \exp
   \left(2 x+\frac{7 i \pi
   }{2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^3\right)\right)+O\left(
   \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^7\right)$$
Now, use
`FullSimplify[Normal[%]]` which will produce
$$\frac{6912 \sinh (x) \cosh (x)}{\pi  x^7}$$ which can simplify.

In fact,
$$\, _2F_3\left(n+\frac{1}{2},n+\frac{3}{2};n,n+\frac{5}{2},2
   n+1;x^2\right)=a_n \, \frac{\sinh(2x) }{\pi \, x^{2 n+1} }+\cdots$$ where the $a_n$ form the (unknown ?) sequence
$$\{10,112,3456,202752,19169280,2654208000,505361203200,\cdots\}$$

**Edit** *(to avoid loosing @Gary's comment)*

$$a_n=2^{2n - 1}\, (2n + 3)\,n!\,(n - 1)!$$

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question!